# MySQL: How to auto record timestamp of last password update

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some way to record time of last password ( or any specific field ) update?

There is good feature in MySQL called triggers but I am not sure that if it is possible to detect specific field update

I have users table having many fields including password.
I just want mysql to automatically update timestamp whenever password field is updated.

Is this really possible through some automatic method like triggers? or Is it only possible with scripting language? 
I can definitely write checks in PHP to update datetime for password update but I want automatic way for this.

Comment: It is possible trough triggers, that's their job.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please guide that how to do it with trigger? How to detect specific field update (not any field ) ?

Comment: You need to read about triggers. They don't detect whether *field* changes. They fire when `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` occurs on a *table*. In trigger body, you receive a list of rows that were affected and then you can compare their old and new values, thus detecting whether something changed.

Comment: @Mjh thanks for the reply. That really makes sense.
I tried that way but I got this error:
`#1442 - Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`
I think we cannot update same table through triggers during update

what do you say?

Comment: Yes, you can't issue an `UPDATE` query. But you can *change* the affected field. You need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on that table, then you need `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN` which will give you a list of changed rows, and then you can access column values with `NEW.column_name` or `OLD.column_name`. `OLD.column_name` is the current (old) value of the column and `NEW.column_name` is the value you're sending via `UPDATE` query. You can change the value by  doing `NEW.timestamp_column_name = NOW()` which sets the timestamp of that row to current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be possible with triggers.
Otherwise you could put the update of the timestamp together with the code where you update the password.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Can you please guide that how to do it with trigger? How to detect specific field update (not any field ) ?